# what is the correct way to determine the height of screen through css?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a layout where i have four colored div's. Say red blue green yellow and all of them equal to height of a page scroll.Its like when i do page down on my screen it should show blue and then green then yellow on load it should show red.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bv6JU/1/ here is the fiddle lets improve it.

Comment: Not sure whats wrong with the question. Just need a layout with four div's having 100% width and height equal to scroll-height. Why closing and negative votes.

Comment: @sushilbharwani: I would guess because you didn't include what you've tried so far, so the question reads more like a request for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: the only thing i am not sure is what to put in the height property. I can give it fixed pixels but doubt that would not work on another machine. I want to be machine independent.

Comment: @colin i dont understand what should i put four divs with width:100% and height:something i am not sure of?

Comment: Add the HTML / CSS you know you would need then have people work from that.

Comment: if you think its still neccessary to put my code, i can put it but doesnt looks like a good idea.

Comment: is there a problem with giving the divs `height:25%' ?

Comment: I think what he wants is, basically, a page that has 4 'screens' (i.e. screen size times 4). At load the full screen is red, then you scroll down and see the blue section, with a height of the screen size. Then green and lastly yellow.

Comment: i have added the jsfiddle for it.

Comment: @Rodolfo thanks for understanding what i want.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with css but I may be wrong. The screen dimensions is known at runtime so you'll probably need to do it using javascript (or jquery easier), and capture the resize event if you want the sizing consistent after someone makes the window bigger or smaller.

Comment: guys now when i have the code added and the explanation by @Rodolfo can someone please give me some direction

Comment: is there some thing in javascript jQuery that i can look for?

Comment: so everyone who do not think its a real question atleast let me know do i need to add more detail or the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in jquery (possibly simple to do in pure javascript too, but I'm a jquery-oholic)...

```
<div class="screensize" style="background-color:red"></div>
<div class="screensize" style="background-color:blue"></div>
<div class="screensize" style="background-color:green"></div>
<div class="screensize" style="background-color:yellow"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".screensize").css("height",$(window).height() + "px");
})
</script>
```

EDIT:
oh, and like I said, if you want to keep the sizing consistent when people resize the window, you would capture the resize event and resize the divs again.  So you would add this line to the function...

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".screensize").css("height",$(window).height() + "px");
})
```

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. If it's possible in jQuery it is possible in JavaScript. Just add `.resize()` to your second bit of JavaScript and erase the first bit.

Comment: @rodolfo something i wanted is achieved by doing some changes in the jsfiddle i posted above http://jsfiddle.net/Bv6JU/2/. I dont understand how it works (specially 100% to html and body css). But solves my problem check if you see a problem

Comment: i dont understand why you have used resize the code works fine with the initial coding only. If you want to check pure css solution. Its in the jsfiddle.net/Bv6JU/2. But i liked the way you have worked on a solution and understood the question. thanks.

Comment: Internet explorer can have some issues with % heights. Check the fiddle in IE to see if it shows for you. It doesn't for me (it does show ok in Firefox, but not in my IE)